# Mapbox: How are tiles sizes and positions calculated

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to get through the learning curve of not just the mapbox api but how map applications work in general. Currently I'm having difficulty understanding the calculation used in sizing and placing tiles based on LngLat and Zoom level.

I checked out the [Slippy maps](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) wiki but it does not seem to align with how mapbox works (or more likely my understanding is incorrect).

I'm hoping someone can point me to a resource that can clearly explain the calculations for the mapbox-gl api tile placement.

Thanks!

More Specifically: I'm trying to figure out how to cover a tile with a 3D plane using [threebox](https://github.com/peterqliu/threebox/blob/master/docs/Threebox.md). To do this I need to:

- get the tile's size (which changes depending on zoom level)
- get the tile's position (which I can get using bbox, however I don't think my calculations are correct because at zoom level 2 the 3D plane's latitude is off by 40.97 degrees when placed using threebox)

My calculation for placing the tiles:

```
var offset = 40.97// temporarily used to fix placement.
var loc_x = bounds[0] + ((bounds[2] - bounds[0])/2); // this works as expected
var loc_y = bounds[1] + offset;
var loc_z = 0;

if (bounds[1] < 0) {
  loc_y = bounds[3] - offset;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what exactly you're asking, could you make your question a bit more specific, a broad general question is hard to answer on stackoverflow. Linking your other very similar question for others who land here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245182/mapbox-get-loaded-tile-coordinates/50246564

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason I needed the offset property. The 3D plane's registration (0,0 coords) needed to match the tile. By default the 3D plane's registration point was in the center of the mesh, rather than the bottom left.